# Remove clear button from datepicker in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, css, mobile, datepicker

Does anyone knows how can I remove the clear button in a datepicker ?. I am using jquery mobile to generate it as follows:

```
<label for="txtDate">Date:<label id="lblDateVisitVal" class="message"></label>
<input id="txtDate" type="date" data-mini="true">
```

Is there anyway I can remove the Clear button shown in the corner or change it for another one?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Label inside label? Anyway, can you please give us a link to datepicker you're using?

Comment: Actually there is no problem with the code. The problem is this code generate a datepicker like the one shown in this link  http://shareourideas.com/2011/10/29/ios-5-and-html5-input-types/ I want to know if there is anyway to remove the "clear" button.

Comment: @Miljan The label inside label was a copy paste error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The native webkit date input (which is what you seem to be using, contrary to the title) [**cannot**](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/08/Quick-FAQs-on-input-type-date-in-Google-Chrome) [be styled](http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/Styling%20Form%20Controls). Unless you're overriding this with a different datepicker, you're stuck with the default appearance.